# Listview with Checkbox using StatefulWidget(setState)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to develop an app in flutter, that has topics that the user can select and check box state will change when i scroll on listview  check box state will not collapse and  finally user give the submit the value are will bring out.i tried i am not able do that.

the error message shows: 
The method 'setState' isn't defined for the class 'ItemDepletionList'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'setState'

```
class ItemDepletion extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GetShaftsState createState() => _GetShaftsState();

}

class _GetShaftsState extends State<ItemDepletion> {
  ItemDepletionBloc _bloc;
  String json =
      '{"RECORD_ID": "0", "REQTYPE": "ITEMDEPELTION", "CLINIC_ID": "1012"}';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _bloc = ItemDepletionBloc(json);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text('Chucky Categories',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20)),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF333333),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF333333),
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: () => _bloc.fetchCategories(json),
        child: StreamBuilder<Response<List<Idepeltion>>>(
          stream: _bloc.chuckListStream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              switch (snapshot.data.status) {
                case Status.LOADING:
                  return Loading(loadingMessage: snapshot.data.message);
                  break;
                case Status.COMPLETED:
                  return ItemDepletionList(
                      itemdepletionlst: snapshot.data.data);
                  break;
                case Status.ERROR:
                  return Error(
                    errorMessage: snapshot.data.message,
                    onRetryPressed: () => _bloc.fetchCategories(json),
                  );
                  break;
              }
            }
            return Container();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _bloc.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}



class ItemDepletionList extends StatelessWidget {
  // final Itemdepeltion categoryList;
  final List<Idepeltion> itemdepletionlst;
  const ItemDepletionList({Key key, this.itemdepletionlst}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new Myappbar(title: new Text("Home Page")),
        body: Column(children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: itemdepletionlst.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                    title: new Container(
                        child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Checkbox(
                        value: itemdepletionlst[index].isCheck,
                        onChanged: (bool value) {
                         setState(() {
                            itemdepletionlst[index].isCheck = value;
                          });
                        }),
                    new Expanded(
                      child: new Container(
                        padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
                        child: new Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Text(
                              '${itemdepletionlst[index].itemName}',
                              style: new TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                fontSize: 16.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            new Text(
                              '${itemdepletionlst[index].category}',
                              style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    new Expanded(
                        child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        selectedItem(
                            context, itemdepletionlst[index].suggQtyUnit);
                      },
                      child: new Container(
                        padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
                        child: new Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Text(
                              '${itemdepletionlst[index].suggReorderQty} ${itemdepletionlst[index].suggQtyUnit}',
                              style: new TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                fontSize: 16.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            new Text(
                              '${itemdepletionlst[index].manuf}',
                              style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    )),
                  ],
                )));
              },
            ),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
           // onPressed: getCheckboxItems,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            child: Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: <Color>[
                    Color(0xFF09a3c8),
                    Color(0xFF39B9B4),
                    Color(0xFF0fb188),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: const Text('Submit',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white)),
            ),
          ),
        ])

        );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **ItemDepletionList** class is **stateless** and You are trying to call setstate in it because of that you are getting that error. make it **Stateful** then it will work.

replace Following line.

```
class ItemDepletionList extends StatelessWidget {
```

With this

```
class ItemDepletionList extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Idepeltion> itemdepletionlst;
  ItemDepletionList({this.itemdepletionlst});
  @override
  _ItemDepletionListState createState() => _ItemDepletionListState();
}

class _ItemDepletionListState extends State<ItemDepletionList> {
```

And now to access itemdepletionlst you have use widget.

```
 widget.itemdepletionlst
```

Comment: above solution working fine but i have one more query where to implement the lazy loading ScrollController() please help me out i implement _GetShaftsState  class but list view loading using this ItemDepletionList .

Comment: what do you mean by lazy loading? what do you want exactly.

Comment: loading more data when list view scroll  end again service call example when first time load record count 30 at end of list view reach again call next 30 so total count load in list view is 60 record

Comment: i don't know perfectly because i haven't implemented yet, but i think it should be in _GetShaftsState because your refresh indicator is in that class and you can pass data in ItemDepletionList class, so you can make change's according.

Comment: can u check it please help out this posts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61675045/load-more-data-using-stream-builder-in-list-view